# AES implementation on Python, Windows

Tags: python, exception, encryption, python-3.x, aes

I've experienced some trouble encrypting and decrypting data between the server and client application I'm developing. I'm using AES implementation using a script that can be downloaded  [here at birth-online.de](http://wiki.birth-online.de/snippets/python/aes-rijndael).

The implementation is working just fine when I'm trying to encode or decode data on my Ubuntu 10.04 Server. However, when trying to use the script under Windows I'm getting the following Exception thrown at me:

```
>>> aes.encrypt("Test", "Test", 256)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "aes.py", line 148, in encrypt
    key = Cipher(pwBytes, KeyExpansion(pwBytes))
  File "aes.py", line 112, in KeyExpansion
    w = [0] * Nb*(Nr+1)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong exactly and how to fix it? I've searched Google already, but can't seem to find anything useful regarding this Exception. I'm using Python 3.2.1 on my Windows (x64) testmachine and my Ubuntu server is running Python 2.6.5. (Could the version make the difference here, by the way?)

Thanks in advance!
Robert

Comment: There is a big difference between Python 2.x and 3.x. Whether or not it's the cause of this particular discrepancy, I don't know, but I'd say it's the prime suspect.

Comment: It seems like this does work in Python 2.7 on Windows. I should have tested that first.. Not so smart of me. However, it still should be possible to run this on Python 3.x cause 2.7 will be getting older and older with no new releases to go. 2.7 is the latest version released for 2.x.

Comment: most packages have to be updated for python 3.  this is the big problem that is slowing adoption of python 3.  you can see at http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all which packages support python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using PyCrypto, I use it in a current project of mine and it has worked very well. You can learn more about it below:

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole AES.py but a first look at your error says that this package is not ready for Python 3.

The problem seems to be "real division" in Python 3. When you do `Nk = len(key)/4` in Python 3, the return value is a float, not an int. To make it an integer division, an extra slash must be added, `Nk = len(key) // 4`.

You can fix AES.py, or go with PyCrypto which is much better in terms of performance.